How many queens of Krishna committed sati after his death?
How many wives of Krishna undergo Sati after his death? Scriptures give contradictory answers. As per Vishnu Purana 8 queens entered pyre:

The eight queens of Kṛṣṇa, who have been named, with Rukminī at their
head, embraced the body of Hari, and entered the funeral fire.
Vishnu Purana:V.38

However as per Mahabharata not all of his 8 chief wives committed sati:

Rukmini, the princess of Gandhara, Saivya, Haimavati, and queen
Jamvabati ascended the funeral pyre. Satyabhama and other dear wives
of Krishna entered the woods, O king, resolved to set themselves to
the practice of penances. They began to live on fruits and roots and
pass their time in the contemplation of Hari.
[Mahabharata Mausala parva Chapter 7]

Which one is correct? Did any scholar throw some light on it?
